# Are writes to eventfd counted as io?

Tags: linux, io, eclipse

I am trying to reduce hard-disk activity on my system. Running `iotop` shows that Eclipse (the IDE, latest version (Luna)) is writing kilobytes of data every few seconds.

So I ran `strace` on the eclipse process and the only `write`s that I can see are to a file-descriptor that points to `eventfd`.

I am not familiar with `eventfd`, but it seems like an event bus of some sort.

Does `write` to it get accounted as a disk write?

Answer (score 1):

If you see a change at "read_bytes" or "write_bytes" in file `/proc/PID_OF_EVENTFD/io` then eventfd reads and writes from or to storage layer.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3634088/3776858

and: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716260/3776858